# Template Variables in Eclipse - var()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin for a C dialect. Currently I'm working on Content Assist and I want to introduce templates for most common language constructs.

In my work I was following [this tutorial](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-enable-template-feature-cu):

I would like to take advantages of templates (specified e.g. [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-template-variables.htm)) such as: `${id:var(type[,type]*)}`, for example to provide template for function call with completion proposals for each function parameter but filtered out to show only proposals of compatible type. Unfortunately I'm not able to find any relevant tutorials or examples.

I would be grateful for any suggestion, links, code snippets, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Grzegorz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I've finally managed to provide such completion proposals. I will explain it briefly but I do not guarantee that this is the right way, but it works :)

If we have a function `foo(boolean bar, boolean baz)` we can create corresponding template: `foo(${bar:var(boolean)}, ${baz:var(boolean)})`. To handle such template we can register custom `TemplateVariableResolver`:

```
public final class VariableResolver extends TemplateVariableResolver {

    public VariableResolver() {
        super("var", "some description");
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(TemplateVariable variable, TemplateContext context) {
        final String name = variable.getName(); /* bar or baz */
        final List params = variable.getVariableType().getParams(); /* ["boolean"] */
        variable.setValues(computeSuggestions(name, params));
        variable.setResolved(true);
    }

    private String[] computeSuggestions(String name, List params) {
        return new String[] {"true", "false"};
        // TODO: more sophisticated proposals
    }

    // overwrite other methods!
}
```

The next step is to make your `CompletionProcessor` extend `TempateCompletionProcessor`.

Here is a (simplified) default implementation of `computeCompletionProposals()` in `TemplateCompletionProcessor`

```
public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int offset) {
    /* some code */
    TemplateContext context= createContext(viewer, region);
    if (context == null)
        return new ICompletionProposal[0];

    context.setVariable("selection", selection.getText()); // name of the selection variables {line, word}_selection //$NON-NLS-1$

    Template[] templates= getTemplates(context.getContextType().getId());
    /* some code */
    return (ICompletionProposal[]) matches.toArray(new ICompletionProposal[matches.size()]);
}
```

Then `VariableResolver` should be registered in `computeCompletionProposals`or somewhere else:

```
context.getContextType().addResolver(new VariableResolver());
```

Therefore if `getTemplates()` will return our exemplary template and user will use it, for parameters `bar` and `baz` `resolve()` will be called, so that we can provide proposals for each `foo` function parameters with regard to these parameter types.